# May someone please explain the translation of "una vez eso fue una escuela"?

Tags: conjunciones

> Una vez eso fue una escuela
>
> That was a school once.

Why is "eso" used rather then "esa"? I would think that the proper conjugation is "esa", in order to agree with the feminine word "escuela".

Comment: Because, in this case, `eso` is not referring to the school, but rather, something else entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "**[demonstrative pronouns](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Pronombre_demostrativo)**" (*ese/esa/eso* among others) can function as **adjectives** (they are attached to a noun) or as **nouns** (they take the place of another noun).

In English a single word can fullfill both functions:

> *I don't like **this** song.*  (**adjective**: '*this*' qualifies the noun '*song*')
>
> *I don't like **this**.*       (**noun**: '*this*' replaces some thing)

In Spanish, though there are no universal rules, but the typical uses are:

***eso* : noun**   : "No me gusta **eso**" [*]

***ese* : adjective, masculine**: "No me gusta **ese sonido**"

***esa* : adjective, feminine**: "No me gusta **esa casa**"

Hence, your example is right. "**eso**" functions as a noun.  A different construction, as adjective, could be "*Una vez **ese** edificio fue una escuela*". "*Una vez **esa** casa fue una escuela*".

[*] The gramatical gender of "eso" is masculine [**], but because it's a noun, not an adjetive, it does not have any concordance rule with the other noun it replaces.
An exception is when the thing alluded is a person, then we normally use the forms "ese/esa" (as nouns).

> "Esa era mi novia"
>
> "Ese es mi tío"

[**] (as per comment) Some prefer to say that "*eso*" is neutral gender. That's true in a semantic sense, in the same sense that in English *he/she/it* are respectively masculine/feminine/neutral. But in Spanish nouns, adjectives, artices and pronouns also (and mainly) have a *gramatical gender* (something English doesn't have at all), which is not directly related with the semantic (the masculinity of the alluded thing) but it's instead tied to concordance rules - and there are no neutral gender here: we have masculine and feminine only. All this is debatable, (lastly, it's about a grammatical terminology) and there are lots of pages discussing this.

Comment: Actually, *eso* is neuter

Comment: Silly me accidentally scrolled past this answer when using the StackExcange mobile app. Excellent answer, now I understand.

Comment: Grammatically, *eso* has neuter gender, though. Only nouns must be masculine/feminine. Clauses and verbs are generally grammatically neuter. Adjectives, articles, and pronouns can be any of the three. The reason it's not super obvious at first glance for many is because in Spanish masculine and neuter adjectives developed from Latin into identical forms. But there is a neuter article (lo), neuter pronouns (ello, esto, eso, aquello, and historically aquesto), and neuter adjectives (ending in -o: *nadar es divertido*, cf. Asturian *nadar ye divertío* [neut]; *el xuegu ye divertíu* [masc])

Comment: It's debatable http://goo.gl/J9fQ3z http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-esquina-del-idioma-genero-neutro-6479/ http://eumanismo.blogspot.com.ar/2008/09/me-muevo-entre-la-sorpresa-de-encontrar.html

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with *esa*, and there's really nothing wrong with *ese* even.  Because a demonstrative pronoun is used, the question is what is in the speaker's mind when they utter *ese/a/o*.  If it's a masculine thing, like *edificio*, they'll use *ese*.  If it's a feminine thing, like *estructura*, they'll use *esa*.  If it can't be reduced to a simple noun, perhaps to refer to the general area (imagine a handwaving around to generalize the location), they'll use *eso*.

Comment: But in the example, 'eso' clearly refers to the feminine noun, "escuela". So isn't the use of "eso" incorrect in this case?

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson actually *escuela* is the least likely thing for it to refer to. It doesn't make much sense to say "That school was once a school". You'll normally be saying that something (currently other than a school) was once a school. If it was translated en->es, the translator probably went with *eso* to avoid referring to anything concrete (since the English one doesn't specify what the *that* is)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the given responses already answer the question. However, as there is still some misunderstanding I'll add some context around the original statement.

> Caminábamos por la calle Alejandría; al pasar por el edificio en ruinas que estaba en la esquina con Venecia mi padre dijo con tristeza: eso que ves ahí, alguna vez fue una escuela.

**Eso** agrees with **edificio en ruinas**. At the very moment when this is being said the **edificio en ruinas** is no longer a school. Thus, in this case it **cannot be *esa***

In fact, gender agreement is not necessary:

> Cuando vimos la casa destruida mi padre dijo: **eso** que ves ahí fue una casa muy hermosa.

We indeed are referring about **la casa**. We are allowed to say **eso** because we are giving the house an indeterminate character. It's **la casa** but it is also **un desastre**, **un desperdicio**, **un atentado contra la estética** or any other meaning you could imagine.

Of course you can always say:

> Cuando vimos la casa destruida mi padre dijo: **esa** que ves ahí fue una casa muy hermosa.

In this case we are deeming the house exactly as house and nothing else.

Now if we refer to women there are some differences. For example, if we are referring to an old woman you must say (to stay polite):

> **Esa** fue una mujer muy bonita

Of course, the woman was never masculine unless it's a trans-gender in which case it's correct to say:

> **Ese** fue una mujer muy bonita

Now, if we wanted to be pejorative we would say

> **Eso** fue una mujer muy bonita (extremely rude and impolite)

---

As a final note, let me add that a writer (or a speaker) has (in Spanish) plenty of resources to give a special hint when trying to communicate with others. I don't really know if this is too subtle for a non-native but I would say that a non-native Spanish speaker that is able to handle these subtleties has an advanced command of the language.